# I can't filter my list of a patch-variable without an error 'expected a literal value'

Tags: filter, netlogo

I'm making a model of hoverflies in which adult hoverflies lay eggs in patches, which hatch after a number of days into larvae. These larvae will turn into pupae when their weight has grown from hatching weight to 28 mg, according to a type 2 functional response to how much they have eaten.
I set up the patches as follows:

```
set peggs n-values 4 [0] ;;number of eggs in a patch. every timestep a number of eggs is added and they hatch after 4 days.

set nl_per_age n-values 20 [0];; number of larvae per age.

set l_hatched n-values 20 [0.0001];; weight of hatched larvae

set l_weight_age n-values 20 [0];; weight of hatched larvae + their individual growth per age

set ppupae n-values 30 [0] ; number of pupae

set larvae 0  ;; larvae biomass
```

Now, in 'to time' (so this code happens every tick) I coded the following:

```
set nl_per_age fput item dtl peggs nl_per_age ;;dtl is 3, so the number of eggs in peggs item 3 are added to the number of larvae

set nl_per_age but-last nl_per_age;  last item is deleted which means that if the larvae haven't grown to 28 mg in 20 days they die

set l_hatched fput ((item dtl peggs) * weight_hatch) l_hatched ;; same as nl_per_age but here the items are multiplied by the hatching weight (0.063)

set l_hatched but-last l_hatched

set l_weight_age map [ larvae-growth ->
     (larvae-growth * 100 * e ^ (g * (aphids)*(1 - (larvae-growth / weight_max))))
     ] l_hatched  ;; this follows a equation from the literature. But what it basically does it that it lets the larvae grow in weight according to the aphid density (prey) in their patch
```

So far so good, but here's where the trouble begins:

```
let larvae_max filter [weight -> weight = 28] [l_weight_age] ;;this filter function should filter out the larvae which weigh 28 mg. BUT: [l_weight_age] gives error 'expected a literal value'. However, when I make up a list like [24 6 21 53 28 28 23 28] this line does work and it counts 3 larvae. 

let number_to_pup length larvae_max ;this counts the number of 28 mg larvae

set ppupae fput number_to_pup ppupae ; the number of larvae of 28 mg are added to ppupae

sprout item dta ppupae ; after 20 days (dta=20) the pupae are sprouted into new turtles.
```

Now the last block of code gives me an error saying 'expected a literal value' at [ l_weight_age]. But I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you mean just `filter [weight -> weight = 28] ll_weight_age`, without the brackets around `ll_weight_age`. It's already a list; if you put brackets around it, NetLogo thinks you're trying to wrap that list in another list.

Comment: That fixed it!! Thanks you so much :). I didn't expect it to be such a simple solution but it works.